# CodeCeption - passing options to a helper

Tags: php, testing, codeception

Is it possible to pass a config parameter to helper class which extends the `\Codeception\Module` class.
I have the following case, I want in my `api.suite.yml` config file in the module enabled section to set for example `Helper\Api` and to set its on `cofig` property.

My idea is to has different environment with different config properties.
Is that possible?

```
class_name: ApiTester
modules:
    enabled:
      - \Helper\Api:      # This is my module
        my_path: C://ssss # This is my custom option I want to pass.
```

My module class.

```
class Api extends \Codeception\Module
{
    protected $requiredFields = ['my_path'];
    ...
}
```

When I ran the suite it fails with:

```
  [Codeception\Exception\ModuleConfigException]
  Helper\Api module is not configured!

  Options: my_path are required
  Please, update the configuration and set all the required fields
```

Comment: Have you read http://codeception.com/docs/06-ReusingTestCode#Configuration ?

Comment: Yes, I read it and I think I made everything as described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had to indent parameter more:

`class_name: ApiTester
modules:
    enabled:
      - \Helper\Api:      # This is my module
          my_path: C://ssss # This is my custom option I want to pass.`